# Standalone, Bootable OS X Applications

Tags: cocoa, macos

What techniques/frameworks are being used by companies like Alsoft (DiskWarrior) to create applications that are bootable without booting into OS X?

I've searched far and wide, and I can't seem to figure out how they're doing it. My guess is that they're using a stripped-down version of OS X, but I'm not at all sure.

Comment: I think it is a stripped-down version of OS X with the boot program changed from Finder to DiskWarrior.

Comment: Exactly, and as far as I know there isn't an official way to do this. In fact, it's a pretty grey area legally in my opinion as without a license from Apple you can't distribute Mac OS X. Alsoft must have come up with a way around this.

Comment: I've read on Alsoft's website after new Apple hardware releases (e.g., new MacBook Pros) that delays in DiskWarrior compatibility updates are expected until "Apple, Inc. releases new system startup files to Alsoft, Inc. and other developers." Any idea what they're talking about?

Comment: @nielsbot The “boot program” isn’t “changed from Finder to DiskWarrior”, since it actually isn’t Finder that is started first, but it is indeed a stripped-down and slightly customised version of OS X.

Comment: alastair--I meant they replace Finder on disk with their own app. (I think there's a WindowServer setting that controls which app is "Finder")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that Alsoft, just like us (Coriolis Systems), will have licensed the bootable DVD development kit from Apple.  In exchange for an annual license fee, this gives us the right to distribute certain parts of Mac OS X (*not* the entire system, I hasten to add), for the specific purpose of booting our utility software.

Contrary to one of the comments above, which suggests there is no official way of doing this, this *is* the official way to go about things.

Alsoft’s remarks on its website reflect the fact that Apple typically takes quite a while to give us updated DVD DDKs, even after releasing new machines that would require them.

Anyway, if you need the ability to do this for some reason, you need to talk to Apple.

Answer (score 4):

To boot from CD on a Macintosh system, you'll need to create an EFI-compatible boot disk.  From there, you can do whatever you want.

Check out http://refit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Of course, this won't allow you to actually run Mac OS X apps.